# How to see the json files of Oxygenbuilder Edits in wordpress database

Tags: wordpress, oxygenbuilder

How to see the json data of Oxygenbuilder Edits in wordpress database?
and to get the post title in it.

I tried:
`SELECT met.*, post.post_title  FROM wp_postmeta as met where met.meta_key = 'ct_builder_json';`

but i want to have with it the post title.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and it worked:

```
SELECT met.*, post.post_title
FROM wp_postmeta as met
   inner join wp_posts post on (met.post_id = post.id)
where met.meta_key = 'ct_builder_json';
```